# How do you search for a branch in SourceTree

Tags: git, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

How do you search for a branch in SourceTree.

It has gotten to the point where i have hundreds of branches and looking through a list in the remote branch tree is next to impossible.

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this is possible directly in SourceTree, but you can grep branches via the command line

```
git branch --all | grep <query>
```

for example

```
git branch --all | grep notifications
```

Will return all branches (remote or local) that contain `notifications` in the name.

Comment: Just another reason why sourcetree sucks

Answer (score 27):

Yes, there is a filter provided in SourceTree at the bottom left corner below the list of all branches. See in the screenshot. 
NOTE: This is on MAC..

[image]

Comment: I dont have it.

Comment: @Antoniossss you can find it inside a repository. I am using sourcetree 4.0 version FYI.

Comment: It seems that 4 is only for mac.

Comment: Correct, I was on mac. What is your OS?

Comment: Update SourceTree to the latest version the search bar will be appeared. My version: 4.0.1 (234)

Comment: Windows only has version 3.4.2 as of 2/16/2021 and lacks this feature.

Comment: On Windows I can't get the search working (SourceTree 3.4.6). On macOS the search UI works ok (SourceTree 4.1.4). It seems like SourceTree version 4 isn't available for windows, hopefully it fixes search on windows.

Comment: It also doesn't work, doesn't show branches for a keyword

Answer (score -1):

In the sourcetree under the left menu look for 'REMOTES' under this you can search the origin where all the branches can be viewed or searched

Comment: but you have to manually scroll down until you find it, or not?

Answer (score -3):

Jump to:
[image: Jump to]

Use the Jump to: option in the top right of the log view.

Comment: Can't search a branch name from the "Jump to" menu. You need to scroll down the list. You can search for a (partial or complete) commit SHA though.